# want to navigate from one page to another page using child module

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Child Module

```
​const routes: Routes = [    
     { path: '', component: ProcComponent,
        children:[{
            path: '/LoadProcResultsdata/:procResults', component: ProcResultsComponent, 
        }]
    }     
];
```

App.Module.ts

```
​const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'app', component: AppComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },    
 { path: 'treeview', component: TreeViewComponent },
 {path:'Proc', loadChildren:'app/proc/Proc.Module#ProcModule'}
```

];

My code

```
this.router.navigate(['/LoadProcResultsdata/'],{ queryParams: { procResults:this.results } });
```

But I am getting following error.

core.umd.js:3064 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'LoadProcResultsdata'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'LoadProcResultsdata'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of issues,

remove front `/` from the path,

```
 children:[{
            path: '/LoadProcResultsdata/:procResults', component: ProcResultsComponent, 
        }]
```

Also you need to use route params rather query params, so you can use below,

```
this.router.navigate(['/LoadProcResultsdata', this.results]);
```

I am assuming `this.results` is some ID, so the resulting url becomes

```
/LoadProcResultsdata/<id>
```

Read more abour route parmeters [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters).

**Update:**

you can do that but not with route params, just with queryParams, remove `:procResults`, and use similar code like below,

```
let extra: any = ['abc','xyz'];

let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  queryParams:extra
};

this.router.navigate(['/LoadProcResultsdata'],navigationExtras);
```

and in the navigted component subscribe to ActivatedRoute queryParams,

```
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
   })
}
```

Check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SvNAF99UqDorCCpcAehV?p=preview)!!

another [Plunker with Lazy loaded module](https://plnkr.co/edit/OHvQ4VkmSsNqS4IxmBzf?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks four response. this.results is a set of string and I want to pass different page. Is there a better way to transfer string or array to a different page.

Comment: @Venu, sure you can pass arrays using queryparams, i have updated my answer and also added  sample Plunker, Cheers!!

Comment: I tried without params, but still giving the same error.,

Comment: yeah.. you used only one module. but mine is lazy loading may be the way i am calling is wrong

Comment: even I removed the / from front.

Comment: @Venu, May be the way you are navigating or your Route configurations aare incorrect, check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OHvQ4VkmSsNqS4IxmBzf?p=preview), this has similar exmple with lazy loaded module, Hope it helps!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152865/discussion-between-venu-and-madhu-ranjan).